# Possible Error - /usr/sbin/dnsmasq

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq

Can someone please verify if what I am seeing is an error or not?
I may have found an error while looking at the running processes using htop. Specifically, it's connected to NetworkManager service:

```
PID    USER        PRI    NI    VIRT    RES    SHR    CPU%    MEM%    TIME+    Command
12927  nobody      20     0     31024   1536   1288   0.0     0.0     0:00.06  /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

The parts that are the queries are:

1. the address: 127.0.1.1 ... is this supposed to be as it is or should it actually be 127.0.0.1? ... therefore, If the address should be 127.0.0.1 ... where does this line come from so that I can change and correct it?
2. the user associated with this service is "nobody", but the user associated with the other NetworkManager services is "root" ... is this the correct / normal user for this service?

Cheers.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add "solved". Instead, click on the tick icon next to the correct answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is exactly what it's supposed to be.

Some commands I ran on my computer:

Excerpt of `ps auxf`:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1025  0.0  0.2 345752  9428 ?        Ssl  Dec17   0:12 NetworkManager
nobody    2294  0.0  0.0  35236  3036 ?        S    Dec17   0:05  \_ /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Excerpt of `sudo netstat -tulnp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2294/dnsmasq    
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           2294/dnsmasq
```

As you can see, the command line arguments passed to dnsmasq are the same. Also, it is listening on 127.0.1.1.